# sendmail mailq what is a filename that ends in 'X'?

Tags: sendmail, mail-queue

I have an mqueue full of files ending in X but I can't work out why they have an 'X', what an 'X' means, and why sendmail wont process them
(googling adding 'X' is too vague it would seem :)

e.g.

```
                /var/spool/mqueue (70 requests)
-----Q-ID----- --Size-- -----Q-Time----- ------------Sender/Recipient-----------
t9QM56ql012231X   99091 Tue Oct 27 09:05 <...

t9R7dTje012912X   97292 Tue Oct 27 18:39 <...
.
.
```

A sample qft9QM56ql012231 start:

```
V8
T1445897106
K0
N0
P129683
Fbs
$_[192.168.0.46]
$rESMTP
$suserPC
${daemon_flags}
${if_addr}192.168.0.240
S<...
rRFC822; ...
RPFD:<...
H?P?Return-Path: <�g>
```

(I've replaced all email addresses with '...' of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man mailq`

> **DESCRIPTION**
>          Mailq prints a summary of the mail messages queued for future delivery.
>
> The  first  line printed for each message shows the internal identifier
>          used on this host for the message with a possible status character, the
>          size  of  the  message  in  bytes,  the  date  and time the message was
>          accepted into the queue, and the envelope sender of the  message.   The
>          second  line  shows  the  error  message that caused this message to be
>          retained in the queue; it will not be present if the message  is  being
>          processed  for  the  first time.  The status characters are either * to
>          indicate the job is being processed; **X to indicate that the load is too
>          high to process the job**; and - to indicate that the job is too young to
>          process.  The following lines show message recipients, one per line.

You can use `uptime` come to get system's load averages.

Comment: Indeed that was the cause "load average: 36.02, 36.08, 36.11" ... looks like a kernel bug in an old kernel ... the system was almost idle ... thanks.